# How do I merge the xarray dataset?

Tags: array-merge

I have eight different xarray data with (7, 375, 121, 240). All the data have same dim, coords, attrb.
I want to make it one xarray data as (7, 375*8, 121, 240).

But when I try mer = xr.merge([ds1,ds2]), it shows the error as below:
MergeError: conflicting values for variable 'hgt' on objects to be combined. You can skip this check by specifying compat='override'.

So I add mer = XR.merge([ds1,ds2], compat='override'), but the result is same as ds1 (7, 375, 121, 240).

How can I mer the xarray dataset as (7, 375*8, 121, 240)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need [xr.concat](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.concat.html), not merge

`ds = xr.concat([ds1, ds2, ...], dim=dim_name)`

where `dim_name` is the name of the second dimension in your array